# How to make button add next FlatList item from Redux object

Tags: javascript, react-native, api, redux

So I have an API that is currently set under the tasks state in my reducer. However, I want to know how to move to the next index within the reducer when I click the button. Currently, if I click the button it constantly adds the current array index name but not the next one since I set the index. Hopefully my code will clarify.
This is my Redux App code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, FlatList, ScrollView, Image, Button } from 'react- 
native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import { Add_Item} from '../redux/actions/index';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return { tasks: state.reducer.tasks };
};
const mapDispatchToProps = {Add_Item};



const url = "https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers";
export function App ({tasks,Add_Item}){
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  React.useEffect (() =>{
    fetch(URL)
    .then (x => x.json())
    .then(json => setData(json))
  })
  return (
    <ScrollView>
      <Button title="Add Text to List" onPress={() => Add_Item(data)} color="blue"/>
      <FlatList data={tasks} renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <View>
              <Text>Name: {item.title[0].name} </Text>
            </View>
          )}
        />
    </ScrollView>
   );
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

This is my action code:

```
import {ADD_ITEM} from "../actionType/index";

export function Add_Item(task_title){
  return {
    type:ADD_ITEM,
    payload:{
      title:task_title,
    }
  }
}
```

This is my reducer code:

```
import { ADD_ITEM } from '../actionType/index';

var initialState = {
tasks: [],
count: 0,
};
export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  if (action.type == ADD_ITEM) {
    return {...state, 
    tasks: [...state.tasks,{title:action.payload.title}]}
  }
  return state;
}
```

Attached is an image of my results so far.
[image]

Also how would I add a remove button to remove the last item from the flatlist?

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do with this code? The `data` state is the entire array of beer data from the API, and each time the button is clicked you are appending the entire array in a single object under a `title` property in the `state.reducer.tasks` array. `action.payload.title` is undefined though since `action.payload` is the entire `data` array. Are you just wanting to one-by-one add the beer names from `data` to the `tasks` array?

Answer (score 0):

If you are just wanting to one-by-one add the beer names from data to the tasks array then I'd suggest using the `tasks` array's length as the index into the fetched beer `data` array for the "beer" you want to create/add a task for. When `tasks` is empty the length is `0`, so `data[0]` will be selected. When `tasks` has 5 elements, the length is `5`, so `data[5]` (*the sixth element*) will be selected.

Example:

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import {
  Text,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  FlatList,
  ScrollView,
  Image,
  Button
} from "react-native";
import { actions } from "./tasks.slice";
import "./styles.css";

const url = "https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers";

function App({ addItem, tasks }) {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch(url)
      .then((x) => x.json())
      .then((json) => setData(json));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ScrollView>
        <Button
          title="Add Text to List"
          onPress={() => addItem(data[tasks.length])}
          color="blue"
        />
        <FlatList
          data={tasks}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <View>
              <Text>Name: {item.title.name}</Text>
            </View>
          )}
        />
      </ScrollView>
    </div>
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  tasks: state.tasks.tasks
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  addItem: actions.addItem
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

The tasks reducer should be updated to save the entire payload instead of an undefined `title` property that doesn't exist on the `data[]` element objects.

```js
export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  if (action.type === ADD_ITEM && action.payload) {
    return {
      ...state, 
      tasks: [...state.tasks, { title: action.payload }]
    };
  }
  return state;
}
```

[image: Edit how-to-make-button-add-next-flatlist-item-from-redux-object]

[image]